# Java Regex to extract json body from a JS callback

Tags: java, regex

I have below String:

```
_mycallback({
   "timestamp":654321,
   "items":[
      {
         "id":111,
         "title":"Test Item 111"
      },
      {
         "id":222,
         "title":"Test Item 222"
      }
   ]
});
```

How can I extract the inner json with java regex? (with nested '{' and '}')

expect output:

```
    {
       "timestamp":654321,
       "items":[
          {
             "id":111,
             "title":"Test Item 111"
          },
          {
             "id":222,
             "title":"Test Item 222"
          }
       ]
    }
```

Comment: So the string that you have contains _mycallback`?

Comment: yes, it looks like a javascript callback, and I just want to extract the json payload of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the function name at the start, remove new lines and spaces, and remove the two last characters:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    String str = "_mycallback({\"timestamp\":654321,\"items\":[{\"id\":111,\"title\":\"TestItem111\"},{\"id\":222,\"title\":\"TestItem222\"}]});";

    str = str.replaceFirst("_mycallback\\(", "");
    str = str.replaceAll("[\n\r\\s]", "");
    str = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(");"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this regex:**

```
"_mycallback\\((\\{.+?\\})\\);"
```

**See regex in context:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "_mycallback({\n"
            + "   \"timestamp\":654321,\n"
            + "   \"items\":[\n"
            + "      {\n"
            + "         \"id\":111,\n"
            + "         \"title\":\"Test Item 111\"\n"
            + "      },\n"
            + "      {\n"
            + "         \"id\":222,\n"
            + "         \"title\":\"Test Item 222\"\n"
            + "      }\n"
            + "   ]\n"
            + "});\n";


    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("_mycallback\\((\\{.+?\\})\\);", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(input);

    if(matcher.find()) {
        String extractedJson = matcher.group(1);

        // Output
        System.out.println(extractedJson);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "timestamp":654321,
    "items":[
        {
            "id":111,
            "title":"Test Item 111"
        },
        {
            "id":222,
            "title":"Test Item 222"
        }
    ]
}
```